# Unexpected search results when querying for files based on mimeType - Google Drive API v3 + Javascript

Tags: google-drive-api

I am trying to search Google Drive for Excel files using the Javascript API (v3). Some Excel files seem to have a mime type of 'application/vnd.ms-excel' and some have a mime type of 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'.

When I use mime type 'application/vnd.ms-excel', the files with that mime type are returned correctly. But, when I use the mime type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' I get a ton of irrelevant results (with mime types like 'x-javascript', 'x-markdown', and even 'image/png').

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Here's my code:

```
function getItemsByQuery(query, callback) {

    var retrievePageOfFiles = function(request, result) {
        request.execute(function(resp) {
            result = result.concat(resp.files);
            var nextPageToken = resp.nextPageToken;
            if (nextPageToken) {
                request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({ 'pageToken': nextPageToken });
                retrievePageOfFiles(request, result);
            }
            else {
                result.length > 0 ? callback(result) : callback([]);
            }
        });
    };

    var q = {'q': query };
    var initialRequest = gapi.client.drive.files.list(q);
    retrievePageOfFiles(initialRequest, []);
}

getItemsByQuery("trashed=false and mimeType='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'", function(results) {
    // Handle results - lots of irrelevant files returned here.
});
```

Comment: Can you show us what the response body looks like where the supposedly irrelevant results are included?

Comment: @abielita I would gladly provide whatever is needed, I'm just not sure what you are asking me to provide. What is it you need me to show you exactly?

Comment: I think @abielita is referring to your statement "But, when I use the mime type 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml‌​.sheet' I get a ton of irrelevant results (with mime types like 'x-javascript', 'x-markdown', and even 'image/png')". abielita wants you to show that response in its raw format to figure out if it's really irrelevant.

Comment: @abielita I simply receive an array of objects from the Javascript API.  See  some examples here: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7XO7WKIwMvEc0RpSjU5YURUdDQ/view?usp=sharing). Is this what you mean by "raw data"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to add the `q` field when rebuilding the query with a `pageToken` field.